# Performance issue while using Parallel.foreach() with MaximumDegreeOfParallelism set as ProcessorCount

Tags: multithreading, performance, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, master-slave

I wanted to process records from a database concurrently and within minimum time. So I thought of using **parallel.foreach()** loop to process the records with the value of **MaximumDegreeOfParallelism** set as **ProcessorCount**.

```
        ParallelOptions po = new ParallelOptions
        {
        };

        po.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = Environment.ProcessorCount;         

        Parallel.ForEach(listUsers, po, (user) =>
        {
            //Parallel processing                
            ProcessEachUser(user);
        });
```

But to my surprise, the CPU utilization was not even close to **20%**. When I dig into the issue and read the MSDN article on this(http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.paralleloptions.maxdegreeofparallelism(v=vs.110).aspx), I tried using a specific value of **MaximumDegreeOfParallelism** as **-1**. As said in the article thet this value removes the limit on the number of concurrently running processes, the performance of my program improved to a high extent.

But that also doesn't met my requirement for the maximum time taken to process all the records in the database. So I further analyzed it more and found that there are two terms as MinThreads and MaxThreads in the threadpool. By default the values of Min Thread and MaxThread are 10 and 1000 respectively. And on start only 10 threads are created and this number keeps on increasing to a max of 1000 with every new user unless a previous thread has finished its execution.

So I set the initial value of MinThread to 900 in place of 10 using

```
   System.Threading.ThreadPool.SetMinThreads(100, 100);
```

so that just from the start only minimum of 900 threads are created and thought that it will improve the performance significantly. This did create 900 threads, but it also increased the number of failure on processing each user very much. So I did not achieve much using this logic. So I changed the value of MinThreads to 100 only and found that the performance was much better now.

But I wanted to improve more as my requirement of time boundation was still not met as it was still exceeding the time limit to process all the records. As you may think I was using all the best possible things to get the maximum performance in parallel processing, I was also thinking the same.

But to meet the time limit I thought of giving a shot in the dark. Now I created two different executable files(**Slaves**) in place of only one and assigned them each half of the users from DB. Both the executable were doing the same thing and were executing concurrently. I created another Master program to start these two Slaves at the same time.
**To my surprise, it reduced the time taken to process all the records nearly to the half.**

Now my question is as simple as that I do not understand the logic behind Master Slave thing giving better performance compared to a single EXE with all the logic same in both the Slaves and the previous EXE. So I would highly appreciate if someone will explain his in detail.

Comment: This very much depends on what the processing logic does. Does it only use CPU? Does it read/write to the disk? Does it use the network somehow?

Comment: It uses the Http Requests to some Web API's hosted in other networks.

Answer (score 1):

> But to my surprise, the CPU utilization was not even close to 20%.
>
> …
>
> It uses the Http Requests to some Web API's hosted in other networks.

This means that CPU utilization is entirely the wrong thing to look at. When using the network, it's your network connection that's going to be the limiting factor, or possibly some network-related limit, certainly not CPU.

> Now I created two different executable files … To my surprise, it reduced the time taken to process all the records nearly to the half.

This points to an artificial, per process limit, most likely [`ServicePointManager.DefaultConnectionLimit`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.servicepointmanager.defaultconnectionlimit.aspx). Try setting it to a larger value than the default at the start of your program and see if it helps.